# Take the derivative of ${\tt tr}\left[X^*P^*PX\right]$ with respect to P, where P is any complex matrix (or linear operator)

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, optimization

I imagine I will have to differentiate with respect to the real and imaginary parts of P separately, but I am honestly having trouble not making sign errors.

Comment: Please follow community guidelines and use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to typeset your notation.

This time, I"ll edit for you.

Comment: Derivatives are simply linear approximations. So how the derivative of a function would look like will be determined by Taylor-expanding the function, and how we represent the derivative (whether it be a linear map, a matrix, or a vector, etc) is a secondary issue. In this case, if we write $f(P)=\operatorname{Tr}(X^*P^*PX)$, then $$f(P+dP) = f(P) + \operatorname{Tr}(X^*(dP)^*PX) + \operatorname{Tr}(X^*P^*(dP)X) + \cdots, $$ hence the map $$Q \mapsto \operatorname{Tr}(X^*Q^*PX) + \operatorname{Tr}(X^*P^*QX)$$ will be the derivative (as linear operator) of $f$ at $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use finite differences:
$$
X^* \; \left(P + \triangle P\right)^* \; \left(P+ \triangle P \right) \; X = \\
X^* \;  \left[
\left(P + \triangle P\right)^* \; \left(P+ \triangle P \right)  \right] X = \\
X^{*} \left[ P^* P + P^* \triangle P + P \triangle P^* + O\left( \; \left| \, \triangle P \, \right|^2 \; \right) \right] X
$$
Subtract from this the expression $X^* \;  P^* \; P \; X$:
$$
X^{*} \left[ P^* \triangle P + P \triangle P^* + O\left( \; \left| \, \triangle P \, \right|^2 \; \right) \right] X.
$$
Thus, the sought derivative is the linear operator that acts on a transformation $H$ by:
$$
H \mapsto {\tt tr} \left( X^{*} \left[ P^* H + P H^*  \right] X \right).
$$

Comment: If I were computing this, would the next step to find a basis for whatever H is drawn from?

Comment: $H$ comes from the tangent bundle of whatever space $P$ lives in.

Comment: If that space is a vector space, then so is the tangent bundle.

Comment: cool, I think I have just barely enough mathematical sophistication to compute something then :).

Comment: Sorry, got carried away.:)  Take $H$ from the same vector space as $P$ is in, and it should do.